# Fast hmset in redis produces null hash

Tags: node.js, redis

I've written a loadtester for my `node` app. My node app uses `redis` as a backend to share information between different clusters (amazon instances) of my app.

When I hit around 100 requests/sec the following code produces `null`

```
redisClient.hmset("visitor:" + userID.toString() + ":" + channel.toString(), {
    "channel": channel.toString(),
    "clusterID": Config.clusterID,              
    "name": randomName.toString()               
});
```

When I then try to see what contents with `hgetall` on:

```
"visitor:" + userID.toString() + ":" + channel.toString()
```

The contents are `null`.

Any ideas how this could be happening?
Note this only happens after reaching 100 requests or more per second.

For my redis server I'm using `ElastiCache` a `t1.micro` instance

Answer (score 1):

Are you waiting the callback for hmset?

It should be

```
var key = "visitor:" + userID.toString() + ":" + channel.toString();
redisClient.hmset(key, {
    "channel": channel.toString(),
    "clusterID": Config.clusterID,              
    "name": randomName.toString()               
}, function(err) {

    redisClient.hgetall(key, function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });    
});
```